# Multiple header in Pandas DataFrame to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I need to export my `DataFrame` to Excel. Everything is good but I need two "rows" of headers in my output file. That mean I need two columns headers. I don't know how to export it and make double headers in `DataFrame`. My `DataFrame` is created with dictionary but I need to add extra header above.

I tried few dumb things but nothing gave me a good result. I want to have on first level header for every three columns and on second level header for each column. They must be different.

I expect output with two headers above columns.

Comment: use `header` option in `to_excel(header=[0, 1])` the same way, `read_excel(header=[0, 1])`

Comment: That's good solution but problem is about that i would have the same columns headers names in second row. for example: max_level, max_level etc. but i can'y have same indexes in dictionary. How to pass it?

Comment: Can you show an example of your data with desired output?

Comment: So ok, now i have working headers with MultiIndex but can you tell me how to choose only few things as a headers?Example:    
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [['A','B', 'C', 'F','E','G','H','I','J','K','L','Z'], ['b','a', 'c','d','e']],
        names=['subject', 'type'])

but now script creates columns with every up letter and down letter. What if i want only for example: A: a,b,c B:d,e not all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Solved by persisting cell-by-cell using worksheet.write(i, j, df.iloc[i,j]), with i starting after the header rows.